# Swiper Slider - Only show on mobile

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Im working on code that init/resize Swiper Slider if screen is smaller than 768px and destoy if is larger.

This code is working but when the browser starts over than width:768px appear a error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: swiper.destroy is not a function
> at swiperMode (home.js:1:817)
> at home.js:1:878

```
    /* Swiper Slider Cards Home - Show only on mobile */
    var swiper = Swiper;
    var init = false;
    function swiperMode() {
      let mobile = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px)");

      if (mobile.matches) {
        if (!init) {
          init = true;
          swiper = new Swiper(".slider-cards-js", {
            direction: "horizontal",
            slidesPerView: "auto",
            centeredSlides: true,
            spaceBetween: 32,
            pagination: {
              el: ".swiper-pagination",
              clickable: true,
            },
          });
        }
      } else {
        swiper.destroy();
        init = false;
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
      swiperMode();
    });

    window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
      swiperMode();
    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solution:

```
var init = false;
var swiper;
function swiperCard() {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    if (!init) {
      init = true;
      swiper = new Swiper(".slider-cards-js", {
        direction: "horizontal",
        slidesPerView: "auto",
        centeredSlides: true,
        spaceBetween: 32,
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
          clickable: true,
        },
      });
    }
  } else if (init) {
    swiper.destroy();
    init = false;
  }
}
swiperCard();
window.addEventListener("resize", swiperCard);
```

Change .slider-cards-js to your swiper main div.

Comment: swiper's destroy function can receive false as the first argument to not destroy the instance entirely so that you can call init() afterwards. However in my experience, the current version of Swiper is buggy in that regard, so destroying it completely as in this answer worked better, though I also had to call disable() before destroy() to have it work properly.